# Flutter local_auth fingerprint authentication without dialog

Tags: dart, flutter, fingerprint

I'm trying to implement fingerprint protection for an app using local_auth in Flutter. [Here's the docs for local_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_auth).

I'm trying to implement the local_auth without any dialogs in the process. The docs do point to  'useErrorDialogs = false' to not use the default dialogs.

What I want to implement is a simple page wherein I can run the auth related stuff at initState() and be able to send the users to the next screen if it's valid or show an error message in the same screen without any popups if the auth was a failure.

Thank you.

Comment: Any update for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment. It is an open issue on flutter's github:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30601